# How to get contact's "FreeBusyStatus" in Microsoft Outlook using REST Api?

Tags: outlook, outlook-restapi, office365-restapi

[image: Specifies the availability status of an attendee for a meeting.]

See above mentioned image, it gives different status but don't know how to get it.
Check [Outlook API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/complex-types-for-mail-contacts-calendar#RESTAPIResourcesUser).

Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{event_id}?$select=ShowAs to retrieve the FreeBusyStatus of attendee(yourself) for a particular meeting, the return type is something like below,

[image]

If you want to check the response from a particular attendee, use GET https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/events/{event_id}?$select=ShowAs,Attendees, and check on the "Response" from the "Status" response.

[image]

Comment: Thank You So Much, I think this response after you created meeting!

_But what if I want to get the status of user before creating meeting?_

I want to set meeting, on the basis of status of other user, like If user "A" is free, then only I'll create meeting otherwise won't.

Answer (score 0):

This enumeration is used for 'Specifies the availability status of an attendee for a meeting.' At present, the Office 365 REST API  is not able to retrieve the contacts' meetings status. And you can submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you want to the Office 365 REST to support this feature.

We are able to add other’s users’ calendar manually, then we could see the status of the appoint/meet of him/her. Here is an figure that show the others calendar for your reference:
[image]

If you want to retrieve the free/busy information of EWS is a possible workaround. Please refer to [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn643673(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more detail. And if you require these information to schedule a meeting, you can try to use the [Find meeting times](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/api/calendar-rest-operations#Findmeetingtimespreview) (preview).